# Elegant sorting algorithm which is considering multiple properties of a class

Tags: c#, .net, sorting

Imagine having list of objects with three DateTime properties (Date1, Date2 and Date3) containing the following data:

- Object1: Date1 (5 July 2019), Date2 (2 July 2019), Date3 (4 July 2019)
- Object2: Date1 (3 July 2019), Date2 (8 July 2019), Date3 (9 July 2019)
- Object3: Date1 (8 July 2019), Date2 (8 July 2019), Date3 (1 July 2019)

As a result for an ascending sort I expect this order: **Object3 > Object1 > Object2** because Date3 of Object3 has the smallest date of all.

I tried to use some fancy Linq methods (`OrderBy()` with `ThenBy()`) but they didn't do what I wanted to achieve.

Comment: So you want to order by the minimum of the three dates?

Comment: So you want to consider Date3 first, then Date2, then Date1? It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: include a complete definition of your sorting rule(s). include the code you wrote so far.

Comment: Sorry if my question is unclear. I want order by the minimum of the three dates.

Comment: Even then, why do you expect O3 -> O2 -> O1? O1.D2 is lower than O2.D1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can order by any transformation using LINQ:

```
var sortedData = data.OrderBy(d => new [] {d.Date1, d.Date2, d.Date3}.Min());
```

Comment: There are no anonymous types used here.

Comment: I really like this solution. Thank you!

Comment: Same, but without specifying the properties one by one: `var sortedData = data.OrderBy(d => d.GetType().GetProperties().Min(p => p.GetValue(d))).ToList();`